# bootsrap nav-bar collapse in small size width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

when the width gets < 768px it show the toggle icon on the right bottom but when I click on it it does not show the list items I defined. can anyone advise me on this? appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/fj0u49bj/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 
    <a>title</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        <a>Link2 </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Log In</a>
        <a>Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you could make a fiddle to reproduce the behavior will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing to load jQuery. Bootstrap.js is build on top of jQuery which means that can not work without it.

If you do have jQuery (before bootstrap.js) than probably your navigation formatting is not properly done.

Have a look at this fiddle (link in the comment below)  so you can see how a  correct nav-bar must be.